# Folding all cells in vs-code notebook view

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

Having received some update, it seems I can now do the following:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to fold *all* cells though, as I can't seem to find an option to do so. Ideally it would work by heading level of the markdown cells, as it does with this single cell.

Answer (score 0):

While clicking on a header or markdown cell, one can use the VSCode shortcut to hide or open cells

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> <- Open with Windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> <- Close with Windows

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> <- Open with Mac

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> <- Close with Mac

Selecting a header will close/open all mark down cells until it finds the next header, and markdown will close/open all cells until it reaches the next markdown cell.

Answer (score -1):

Select all cells (Ctrl+A) and then run "Fold Cell" as lined out in the question.

Comment: This does not work.